# Select and Deselect in Laravel and Javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5

I'm creating a function which allows a user to select and deselect multiple products with Javascript, The problem is it shows only one checkbox instead of each product to have its checkbox .If I have 20 products it shows 1 checkbox for the first product, how can I fix this?

Blade file

```
<span><a class="Select-Deselect" href="">Select</a></span>

   @foreach($products as $product)
    <div id="checkBox1" style=" display:none; position:absolute;">
       <h1>hello</h1>
     </div>
  @endforeach
```

Javascript

```
    <script>
    /* Select deselect */
    $(".Select-Deselect").click(function(e) {
if ($(this).html() == "Select") {
    document.getElementById("checkBox1").style.display="block";
    $(this).html('Deselect');


}
else {
    $(this).html('Select');
    document.getElementById("checkBox1").style.display="none";
}
return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: You have multiple elements with `id="checkBox"` on your page. `id` attributes must be unique. Maybe use a class instead

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get that can you please explain more? @kerbh0lz

Comment: In your loop you are creating multiple `<div id="checkBox">`. There can be only _one_ element/div with `id="checkBox"` in your document. The `id` attributes must all be unique, like `<div id="checkBox1">`, `<div id="checkBox2">` etc. That's why `document.getElementById("checkBox")` only gets the first of those elements. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

Comment: I have tried to change and put only one div inside the loop but still doesn't work? @kerbh0lz

Comment: It doesn't matter how many divs you put inside of the loop, it's important that there are no duplicate `id`s when you view the source of your document. Can you maybe update your question to show the new code?

Comment: Please check the update. I have made it in a simple way, I want that `hello` to be in each product. @kerbh0lz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop you are again creating multiple divs with the same `id` attribute. Remove the `id` attribute and use a `class` instead, as said, `id` attributes must be unique in a document.

Change your `<a>` to select/deselect to a button, that's more suitable:

Since you already use jQuery in your script I also used it to toggle the `display` style on the elements.

I removed the `id="checkBox1"` and replaced it with `class="checkbox-container"`. Using a class makes it possible to select more than one element, that's what `$(".checkbox-container")` does.

Here's a working example:

blade:

```
<button class="Select-Deselect" type="button">Select</button>

@foreach($products as $product)
<div class="checkbox-container" style="display:none;">
  <h1>hello</h1>
</div>
@endforeach
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
$(".Select-Deselect").click( function(e) {
  if ($(this).html() == "Select") {
    $(".checkbox-container").css('display', 'block');
    $(this).html('Deselect');
  } else {
    $(".checkbox-container").css('display', 'none');
    $(this).html('Select');
  }
  return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is working but I just want to know why  `position:absolute` doesn't work well with this because if I put `position:absolute` it shows only one element like before. @kerbh0lz

Comment: Because you don't set any `top`, `left`, `right` or `bottom` properties for the elements so they both are located at the same position

Comment: Well, I have just tried to put paddings and left ,right, bottom but not working and in my case I have to use `position:absolute`. Do you have any idea maybe to make this work? @kerbh0lz

Comment: Not sure how you applied padding and bottom etc. but if you did it in your loop all of your elements would have the same padding etc. and thus still remain overlayed on the same posittion. I really see no reason why you would _have_ to use an **absolute** position here. What is the reason? This sounds like a different problem for a different question.